# How to initialize nested struct in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, nested, initialization, c++20

Let's say I have following declaration in the C++:

```
struct Configuration {

 struct ParametersSetA {
    float param_A_01;
    float param_A_02;
        float param_A_03;
 } parameters_set_A;

 struct ParametersSetB {
    float param_B_01;
    float param_B_02;
 } parameters_set_B;

};
```

Then somewhere in the code I have following definition:

```
Configuration config = {
 
 .parameters_set_A = {
  .param_A_01 = 1.0f,
  .param_A_02 = 2.0f, 
  .param_A_03 = param_A_01 + param_A_02;
  },

 .parameters_set_B = {
  .param_B_01 = 0.50f,
  .param_B_02 = 0.75f
  }
};
```

My question is whether the initialization (especially as far as the `param_A_03` item in the nested struct `ParametersSetA`)
I have used above is correct in the C++?

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: It is not going to compile, so I guess the obvious answer is no. But it is easy to fix: `param_A_01` -> `config.parameters_set_A.param_A_01` and similar for the other. And the semicolon after that line doesn't belong there either.

Comment: Related: [Nested designated initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70046617/nested-designated-initializers)

Comment: The **problem** is that you *can't use* `param_A_01 + param_A_02` when initializing `param_A_03`.

Comment: [Designated initializes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) are available since C++20, so please add respective tag if this limitation is intentional.

Comment: If you always initialize the member like that, you can give it a default initializer like `float param_A_03 = param_A_01 + param_A_02;` inside the struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that we can't use any of the **unqualified names** `param_A_01` or `param_A_02` or an expression that involves any of the two like `param_A_01 + param_A_02` as initializer for`param_A_03`.

**Additionally**, you have incorrectly put a semicolon `;` after `param_A_01 + param_A_02` instead of comma `,` . I've corrected both of these in the below shown modified program:

##### Method 1

```
//create constexpr variables 
constexpr float A1 = 1.0f;
constexpr float A2 = 2.0f;
Configuration config = {
 
 .parameters_set_A = {
  .param_A_01 = A1,
  .param_A_02 = A2, 
//--------------vv---vv---->use those constexpr variable(also semicolon is removed from here)
  .param_A_03 = A1 + A2
  },

 .parameters_set_B = {
  .param_B_01 = 0.50f,
  .param_B_02 = 0.75f
  }
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f38KjKfEP)

##### Method 2

Other option is to use **qualified names** like `config.parameters_set_A.param_A_01` and `config.parameters_set_A.param_A_02` as shown below:

```
Configuration config = {
 
 .parameters_set_A = {
  .param_A_01 = 1.0f,
  .param_A_02 = 2.0f, 
//--------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--->qualified name used here
  .param_A_03 = config.parameters_set_A.param_A_01 + config.parameters_set_A.param_A_02 
  },

 .parameters_set_B = {
  .param_B_01 = 0.50f,
  .param_B_02 = 0.75f
  }
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8e4863Kqr)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My original intention was to calculate the initialization value for the `param_A_03` based on the values of `param_A_01` and `param_A_02` at compile time. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Steve One option is to create constexpr variables for `param_A_01` and `param_A_02` called `A1` and `A2` respectively and then use those. See [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YvTvzxPzh). You're welcome.

Comment: I see, thanks. Let's say I would like to avoid the constexpr variables. Is it ok to use the variant mentioned  above by the user17732522?

Comment: @Steve Yes, you can use the **qualified names** `config.parameters_set_A.param_A_01` and `config.parameters_set_A.param_A_02`. I've added that as method 2 in my answer.